# How to compare the name of a Person in different representation using C#

Tags: c#

I am having a scenario where a comparision of two representaions of the same name needs to be validated. For example
Lets say name of person **1** is represnted as

> Person1Name= Venkata Phani Kumar Parimi

Lets say name of same person **2** is represnted as

> Person2Name= Kumar Parimi Venkata Phani

One more scenarios is

> John F. Kennedy = John Fitzgerald Kennedy

The above is of higher priority when compared to the below case.

> John F. Kennedy = John Kennedy

Even in two different Contexts the above two persons reffer to the same person.

Please let me know if there is a way using C# to compare and confirm the names belong to the same person

Comment: You probably need a better definition of the problem. Two names could refer to different people even if the names are identical.

Comment: @phoog : I am not considering that case at this point of time.

Comment: @DanielA.White: I tried to implement this using Lists which is really a poor option to consider and also missed out the newly added sceanrio..

Comment: @PhaniKumarPV Okay, but my point is this: how do you define your test that two names refer to the same person?  The most important problem in answering your question is to define the rules dictating the logic of the comparison.  We can't do that for you, because we don't know the larger context.  Once the rules are defined, writing the code is most likely trivial, but that *is* something we can help with.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very context specific problem, so I think you need to address it as such. First, what actually *makes* two names equal? Is it that it contains the same names, in any order? Then that is what you need to detect. Can there be abbreviations? Can there be titles such as "Mrs."? If there are double names with hyphens, what happens? I think your example doesn't describe the problem you have in enough detail. You need to provide more examples of names that are equal and unequal, as well as *why* those names are equal, before anyone can provide you with an algorithm.

i.e.

> John F. Kennedy = John Fitzgerald Kennedy  ?
>
> Mr. John F. Kennedy = John Kennedy ?

It gets even worse if you look at different spellings.

> Yaya Touré = Toure Yaya  ?

With such issues the problem quickly becomes very complicated. If you only need to compare two sets for equality and you can ignore spelling, abbreviations, titles etc. then just check the set intersection. In c#-like pseudocode

```
string[] names1 = name1.ToLowerInvariant().Split(' ');
string[] names2 = name2.ToLowerInvariant().Split(' ');

if (names1.Length != names2.Length)
   return false; // unequal, different number of names

foreach(name in names1)
   if (!names2.Contains(name))
       return false; // unequal, missing name
 
return true; // equal
```

Comment: Thanks for Pointing me the missed out scenario. Updated the Q with the scenario information.

Answer (score 0):

try using `SequenceEqual` this is exactly its job:

```
  string s = "Subba Cargos";
  string s2 = "Cargos Subba";

  var isSame=  s.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).
               OrderBy(o => o).SequenceEqual(s2.Split(new[] {' '}, 
                   StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).
               OrderBy(o => o));
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you like brevity:

```
        var person1name = "Venkata Phani Kumar Parimi";
        var person2name = "Kumar Parimi Venkata Phani";

        var match = person1name.Split().All(p => person2name.Split().Contains(p))
```